# Windowed writes in python, e.g. to NetCDF

Tags: python, large-data, netcdf

In python how can I write subsets of an array to disk, without holding the entire array in memory?

The `xarray` input/output docs note that xarray does not support incremental writes, only incremental reads except by streaming through `dask.array`. (Also that modifying a dataset only affects the in-memory copy, not the connected file.) The `dask` docs suggest it might be necessary to save the entire array after each manipulation?

Comment: Seems to be possible using HDF5 (`h5py`) by calling `.flush()` after each assignment to a subset of the dataset/array. Not sure whether it is also possible with NetCDF?

Comment: how are you opening the NetCDF? if you are using `xarray`'s `open_dataset` and specify the `chunks` parameter, then the NetCDF will be loaded in memory chunk by chunk: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `netCDF4` (the python library of low level NetCDF bindings). Simply assign to a slice of a dataset variable, and optionally call the dataset `.sync()` method afterward to ensure no delay before those changes are flushed to the file.

Note this approach also provides the opportunity to progressively grow a dimension of the array (by calling `createDimension` with size `None`, making it the first dimension of a variable, and iteratively assigning to incrementally larger indices along that dimension of the variable).

Although random-access window (i.e. subset) writes appear to require the lower level package, more systematic subset writes (eventually covering the entire array) can be done incrementally with `xarray` (by specifying a chunk size parameter to trigger use of the `dask.array` backend), and provided that your algorithm is refactored so that the main loop occurs in the dask/xarray store-to-file call. This means you will not have explicit control over the sequence in which chunks are generated and written.